# How can I access the raw HTTP request data with PHP/apache?

Tags: php, apache

I was wondering if there was a way to get at the raw HTTP request data in PHP running on apache that doesn't involve using any additional extensions. I've seen the [HTTP](https://www.php.net/http) functions in the manual, but I don't have the option of installing an extension in my environment.

While I can access the information from $_SERVER, I would like to see the raw request exactly as it was sent to the server. PHP munges the header names to suit its own array key style, for eg. Some-Test-Header becomes HTTP_X_SOME_TEST_HEADER. This is not what I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean the information contained in `$_SERVER`?

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Edit:

Would this do then?

```
foreach(getallheaders() as $key=>$value)  {
    print $key.': '.$value."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want the raw request before it gets parsed into $_SERVER by PHP

Answer (score 12):

Use the following php wrapper:

```
$raw_post = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: I don't think that gets the http headers though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  $request = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] .' '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\r\n";
  
  foreach (getallheaders() as $key => $value) {
    $request .= trim($key) .': '. trim($value) . "\r\n";
  }
  
  $request .= "\r\n" . file_get_contents('php://input');
  
  echo $request;
```